# InvocationTargetException on FCM message received caused by NoSuchMethodError

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

When an FCM message is sent to the device. The app crashes with this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzz(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzaa; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa' appears in /data/data/com.dodum.ahivelnr/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.android.gms-play-services-basement-9.6.1_edeb30b4cf5821e3a8ccd94cce4eee06ac81c766-classes.dex)
 at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzx.zzbd(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement.getInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
 at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source) 
 at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
 at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
 at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
 at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
 at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1748) 
 at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1723) 
 at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5197) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4792) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4732) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1424) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I am using the latest FCM version:

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1
```

Also the latest gradle:

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1
```

I have added `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'`

and added plugin `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Comment: Provide your activity related to FCM.

Comment: There's nothing related to FCM in the activity.

Comment: Then why are you using FCM? You must have FCM Messaging and Instance ID services implemented on client side to use FCM

Comment: I have the services implemented. But it doesn't require an activity to start it as the receiver service is launched when the application starts

Comment: @suku As far as I know, this error occurs when Firebase Instance ID services dependency is not properly implemented. Make sure your manifest is proper and `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` is declared outside at the bottom of dependencies. Also Mention @RushiMThakker otherwise I won't know you replied to my comment

Comment: @RushiMThakker i had not added the google-services plugin below the dependencies but at the top below the android-application . I must not have read the documentation properly. Can you write your above comment as the answer. I'll mark it answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` is declared outside **below** the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You should also add **com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1** to your dependencies

Comment: Without that added I wouldn't have even seen this error

Comment: @suku but i've seen this error without firebase-core. And it was exactly the same as yours.

Comment: Why would firebase core need to be added for fcm...it works without it

Comment: @suku I had NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzz without adding firebase core. And it was gone after I added firebase core.

Comment: OK...because after I changed the code as @rushi suggested, the fcm was working fine...I had not added the firebase core